# GDM don't show available users list and don't switch layout

Tags: fedora

Good night!
I can't login through GDM but can via terminal.
Also I can't change layout but successfully do it via terminal.

This is example of /var/log/messages endline:

`gdm-simple-greeter[...]: Couldn't enumerate devices
...the permission of the setuid helper is not correct...`

And this "permission of the setuid" is everywhere in GDM logs. What the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for just posting links but I cannot reproduce the problem myself. I hope this is useful none the less.

There is a [thread on this problem on ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1126653)

The solution there was

- log in tty1 console as root
- stop gdm
- startx
- Now if you are able to see the desktop, connect to the internet and reinstall dbus related stuff from synaptic.

[Another thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=627339) suggests the following command may also work

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome
```

Comment: I tried this, but can't stop gdm. This logon window is popups again and again. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: You could re-install the "dbus related stuff" from the console on tty1. You get there using (Ctrl+Alt+F1). Use apt-get to install packages. I cannot provide much help as I cannot reproduce the problem. Sorry

Comment: Reinstalling dbus (rather than gnome, which I didn't try) solved a similar problem for me on CentOS 6